# Styling the_posts_pagination With Font Awesome

Tags: pagination

I am using the_posts_pagination to create my pagination links on Wordpress, however I would like to replace 'prev' and 'next' with Font Awesome icons.  Is this possible?

I am already using Font Awesome elsewhere on the site.

Kind regards
James

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know how I can do it?!

Comment: Added sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text with the funcion for example.

```
the_posts_pagination( array(
        'prev_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>', 'textdomain' ),
        'next_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>', 'textdomain' ),
    ) );
```

Use whatever icons you can, I used `fa-arrow` icons.

Comment: Thank you very much for this - it didn't actually work placing it in functions.php but it worked perfectly directly in the page.